# Using the Navigator class with no buttons (i.e. onPressed...) in a void method

Tags: flutter, navigator

I have a method that gets called based on a condition for a password:

```
void passwordLogic() {
  if(equals(password,correctPassword)){
      //// I want to switch to another screen here.
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return Main();
      }));
  }
```

but the context after "push" throws an error: undefined name 'context'.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get the context as a parameter of the function, i.e., `void passwordLogic(BuildContext context)`

Corrected code:

```
void passwordLogic(BuildContext context) {
  if(equals(password,correctPassword)){
      //// I want to switch to another screen here.
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return Main();
      }));
  }
```